# Chcecking the responde code of given URLs - Script don`t stop after checking all URL`s

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, terminal

I have made a script below. The script is checking responde code of every URL listed in the for example .csv file in column A. Everything works as I planed but after checking all URL`s the script is freezed. I have to do ctrl+c combination to stop it. How can I make script automaticly end the run after all URL's are checked.

```
#!/bin/bash
for link in `cat $1` $2;
do
response=`curl --output /dev/null --silent --write-out %{http_code} $link`;
if [ "$response" == "$2" ]; then
echo "$link";
fi
done
```

Comment: How are you running the script (exact command line)? What are the contents of `example.csv`? Without further details this is not reproducible.

Comment: no, it's not checking everything in column A. It's iterating over each word in the file, seperated by whitespace. Nothing here handles csv or columns.

Comment: I run the script "bash {my_script.sh} {example.csv} {response_code}".  In {response_code} I put the response code I needed to check 200, 301, 404 etc. The example.csv contains URL`s addresses in column A. Each row contains one URL adress.

I get the result in the form of address lists that contain the response code that I indicated. Only the script does not stop when it check all addresses from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script hangs due to `$2` in the `for link` line (when it hangs, check `ps aux | grep curl` and you'll find a curl process with the response code as the last argument). Also, `` for link in `cat $1` $2 `` is not how you should read and process lines from a file.

Assuming your `example.csv` file only contains one URL per row and nothing else (which basically makes it a plain text file), this code should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read -r link; do
    response=$(curl --output /dev/null --silent --write-out %{http_code} "$link")
    if [[ "$response" == "$2" ]]; then
        echo "$link"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you for explaining me how wrong my thinking was. This is also valuable code to study and deepen knowledge is this area...

Answer (score -1):

Copying your code verbatim and fudging a test file with a few urls separated by whitespace to test with, it does indeed hang.  However, removing the `$2` from the end of the `for` allows the script to finish.

```sh
for link in `cat $1`;
```

Comment: yes, but this is not the case. If I remove $2 from the FOR loop I won't be able to define response code I want to check in URL`s